# Github Actions: Is it possible to reference a repository variable or environment variable within "uses" context?

Tags: github-actions

My goal is to set the version of used github actions within either environment variables or repository secrets I can set within the github web interface.

For example:

```
example-job:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: example-step
      uses: example-repo/example-composite-action@${{ vars.ACTION_VERSION }}
```

If I try this I'm getting a `Unrecognized named-value: 'vars'.` I tried the same with `env` with a similar result.

Is it somehow possible to set the version of composite action more dynamically without doing a PR everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use variables in composite action URLs. And that's to avoid any breaking changes from actions in consuming pipelines.

As an alternative you can use the [`actions/checkout@v3`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) to checkout your composite action repository and reference it locally in your pipeline, for example:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Checkout actions repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: my-org/my-actions
    path: my-actions
    ref: @${{ vars.ACTION_VERSION }}

- uses: ./my-actions/.github/actions/example-composite-action
```